# Can I do state space quantization using a KMeans-like algorithm instead of range buckets?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, k-means, dimensionality

Are there any reference papers where it is used a KMeans-like algorithm in state space quantization in Reinforcement Learning instead of range buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this paper [Representation and Reinforcement Learning for
Personalized Glycemic Control in Septic Patients](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00654.pdf), presented in the Machine Learning for Health Workshop in NIPS 2017. Here is a quote from the paper where the authors describe the clustering approach:

> After we generated the state representation,
>   we used the k-means clustering algorithm to categorize millions of patient states into 500 clusters
>   such that similar clinical states can collapse into the same cluster.